# Build fails - Type or namespace name 'SwaggerWcf' could not be found - unless I remove PublicKey attribute

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, swagger-wcf

**SwaggerWcf** shows as a broken Nuget reference under project references in VS2017

If I remove the **PublicKey** attribute from the csproj file, the problem is fixed.

Uninstalling and reinstalling via Nuget Gui in VS creates exactly the same failure again.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Hi, do you meet this error message when you install this package 'SwaggerWcf' or add the using statement? This error often caused by the .NET Framework version incompatibility, please right click the project name and choose Properties to check the target framework, make sure it is a full framework and the version not an older one. I tried to install and use this package, unable to reproduce this error message, would you please share your project type and also have a look at your VS version?

Comment: This happened initially when I cloned the repo and built it for the very first time, on a clean machine.

Comment: If you create a new solution, install the package 'SwaggerWcf' and build it, does this issue persists or not? Please help to check if this issue happen to all projects or just cloned repo.